# STM32 (H7) DMA Callback Imbalance for SAI vs I2S (same clock frequency, one is called slightly more / less often)

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx, stm32h

I have a strange issue here trying to read 2x PDM mics from the **SAI peripheral** and output the audio over the **I2S peripheral** here on the H7.

I use what appears to be the correct frequency for both peripherals and clear audio coming out, until the imbalance gets to be too much after some seconds. The SAI is called about 1.01 (approximately) **times more often per second** than the I2S peripheral. **Cube MX shows a clock error of 0% for both**.

The callback imbalance causes the audio to become distorted once the FreeRTOS queue is full. This queue currently just queues and de-queues items. It will later be used for processing of audio samples away from the DMA Callbacks. Whether this queue is in place or not, it doesn't make a difference. I count the difference in callbacks simply with a callbackImbalance variable, incrementing or decrementing it.

Simply put, **HAL_SAI_RxCpltCallback** (and half) is called **slightly more often** than **HAL_I2SEx_TxRxCpltCallback** (and half).

If I reduce or increase the SAI clock, the amount of the callback imbalance is changed, however this doesn't seem like the right solution as I cannot get the imbalance to go away, just by guessing. The cocks seem to be exactly correct.

SAI: 2.048 Mhz, no divider (Decimation Ratio * Channels * Sample Rate) = 2048000

I2S: 2.048 Mhz, seems to divide internally as there is no settings for it in Cube MX

[image: Clock Configuration]
[image: SAI Peripheral]
[image: I2S Peripheral]

Here is a log printed from the I2S Complete Callback. As you can see, at call # 382 the imbalance starts, with the SAI being called but I2S hasn't.

```
--> Started...
--> Starting algorithm loop back...
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 1, I2S: 1
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 2, I2S: 2
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 3, I2S: 3
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 4, I2S: 4
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 5, I2S: 5
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 6, I2S: 6
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 7, I2S: 7
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 8, I2S: 8
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 9, I2S: 9
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 10, I2S: 10
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 11, I2S: 11
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 12, I2S: 12
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 13, I2S: 13
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 14, I2S: 14
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 15, I2S: 15
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 16, I2S: 16
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 17, I2S: 17
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 18, I2S: 18
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 19, I2S: 19
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 20, I2S: 20
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 21, I2S: 21
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 22, I2S: 22
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 23, I2S: 23
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 24, I2S: 24
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 25, I2S: 25
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 26, I2S: 26
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 27, I2S: 27
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 28, I2S: 28
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 29, I2S: 29
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 30, I2S: 30
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 31, I2S: 31
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 32, I2S: 32
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 33, I2S: 33
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 34, I2S: 34
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 35, I2S: 35
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 36, I2S: 36
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 37, I2S: 37
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 38, I2S: 38
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 39, I2S: 39
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 40, I2S: 40
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 41, I2S: 41
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 42, I2S: 42
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 43, I2S: 43
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 44, I2S: 44
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 45, I2S: 45
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 46, I2S: 46
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 47, I2S: 47
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 48, I2S: 48
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 49, I2S: 49
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 50, I2S: 50
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 51, I2S: 51
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 52, I2S: 52
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 53, I2S: 53
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 54, I2S: 54
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 55, I2S: 55
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 56, I2S: 56
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 57, I2S: 57
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 58, I2S: 58
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 59, I2S: 59
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 60, I2S: 60
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 61, I2S: 61
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 62, I2S: 62
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 63, I2S: 63
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 64, I2S: 64
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 65, I2S: 65
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 66, I2S: 66
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 67, I2S: 67
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 68, I2S: 68
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 69, I2S: 69
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 70, I2S: 70
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 71, I2S: 71
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 72, I2S: 72
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 73, I2S: 73
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 74, I2S: 74
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 75, I2S: 75
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 76, I2S: 76
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 77, I2S: 77
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 78, I2S: 78
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 79, I2S: 79
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 80, I2S: 80
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 81, I2S: 81
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 82, I2S: 82
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 83, I2S: 83
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 84, I2S: 84
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 85, I2S: 85
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 86, I2S: 86
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 87, I2S: 87
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 88, I2S: 88
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 89, I2S: 89
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 90, I2S: 90
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 91, I2S: 91
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 92, I2S: 92
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 93, I2S: 93
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 94, I2S: 94
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 95, I2S: 95
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 96, I2S: 96
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 97, I2S: 97
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 98, I2S: 98
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 99, I2S: 99
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 100, I2S: 100
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 101, I2S: 101
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 102, I2S: 102
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 103, I2S: 103
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 104, I2S: 104
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 105, I2S: 105
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 106, I2S: 106
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 107, I2S: 107
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 108, I2S: 108
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 109, I2S: 109
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 110, I2S: 110
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 111, I2S: 111
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 112, I2S: 112
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 113, I2S: 113
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 114, I2S: 114
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 115, I2S: 115
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 116, I2S: 116
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 117, I2S: 117
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 118, I2S: 118
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 119, I2S: 119
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 120, I2S: 120
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 121, I2S: 121
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 122, I2S: 122
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 123, I2S: 123
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 124, I2S: 124
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 125, I2S: 125
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 126, I2S: 126
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 127, I2S: 127
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 128, I2S: 128
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 129, I2S: 129
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 130, I2S: 130
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 131, I2S: 131
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 132, I2S: 132
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 133, I2S: 133
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 134, I2S: 134
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 135, I2S: 135
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 136, I2S: 136
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 137, I2S: 137
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 138, I2S: 138
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 139, I2S: 139
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 140, I2S: 140
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 141, I2S: 141
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 142, I2S: 142
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 143, I2S: 143
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 144, I2S: 144
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 145, I2S: 145
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 146, I2S: 146
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 147, I2S: 147
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 148, I2S: 148
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 149, I2S: 149
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 150, I2S: 150
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 151, I2S: 151
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 152, I2S: 152
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 153, I2S: 153
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 154, I2S: 154
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 155, I2S: 155
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 156, I2S: 156
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 157, I2S: 157
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 158, I2S: 158
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 159, I2S: 159
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 160, I2S: 160
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 161, I2S: 161
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 162, I2S: 162
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 163, I2S: 163
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 164, I2S: 164
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 165, I2S: 165
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 166, I2S: 166
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 167, I2S: 167
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 168, I2S: 168
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 169, I2S: 169
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 170, I2S: 170
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 171, I2S: 171
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 172, I2S: 172
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 173, I2S: 173
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 174, I2S: 174
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 175, I2S: 175
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 176, I2S: 176
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 177, I2S: 177
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 178, I2S: 178
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 179, I2S: 179
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 180, I2S: 180
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 181, I2S: 181
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 182, I2S: 182
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 183, I2S: 183
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 184, I2S: 184
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 185, I2S: 185
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 186, I2S: 186
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 187, I2S: 187
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 188, I2S: 188
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 189, I2S: 189
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 190, I2S: 190
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 191, I2S: 191
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 192, I2S: 192
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 193, I2S: 193
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 194, I2S: 194
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 195, I2S: 195
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 196, I2S: 196
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 197, I2S: 197
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 198, I2S: 198
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 199, I2S: 199
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 200, I2S: 200
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 201, I2S: 201
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 202, I2S: 202
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 203, I2S: 203
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 204, I2S: 204
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 205, I2S: 205
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 206, I2S: 206
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 207, I2S: 207
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 208, I2S: 208
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 209, I2S: 209
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 210, I2S: 210
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 211, I2S: 211
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 212, I2S: 212
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 213, I2S: 213
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 214, I2S: 214
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 215, I2S: 215
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 216, I2S: 216
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 217, I2S: 217
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 218, I2S: 218
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 219, I2S: 219
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 220, I2S: 220
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 221, I2S: 221
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 222, I2S: 222
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 223, I2S: 223
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 224, I2S: 224
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 225, I2S: 225
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 226, I2S: 226
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 227, I2S: 227
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 228, I2S: 228
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 229, I2S: 229
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 230, I2S: 230
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 231, I2S: 231
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 232, I2S: 232
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 233, I2S: 233
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 234, I2S: 234
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 235, I2S: 235
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 236, I2S: 236
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 237, I2S: 237
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 238, I2S: 238
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 239, I2S: 239
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 240, I2S: 240
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 241, I2S: 241
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 242, I2S: 242
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 243, I2S: 243
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 244, I2S: 244
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 245, I2S: 245
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 246, I2S: 246
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 247, I2S: 247
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 248, I2S: 248
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 249, I2S: 249
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 250, I2S: 250
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 251, I2S: 251
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 252, I2S: 252
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 253, I2S: 253
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 254, I2S: 254
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 255, I2S: 255
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 256, I2S: 256
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 257, I2S: 257
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 258, I2S: 258
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 259, I2S: 259
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 260, I2S: 260
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 261, I2S: 261
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 262, I2S: 262
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 263, I2S: 263
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 264, I2S: 264
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 265, I2S: 265
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 266, I2S: 266
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 267, I2S: 267
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 268, I2S: 268
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 269, I2S: 269
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 270, I2S: 270
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 271, I2S: 271
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 272, I2S: 272
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 273, I2S: 273
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 274, I2S: 274
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 275, I2S: 275
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 276, I2S: 276
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 277, I2S: 277
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 278, I2S: 278
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 279, I2S: 279
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 280, I2S: 280
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 281, I2S: 281
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 282, I2S: 282
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 283, I2S: 283
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 284, I2S: 284
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 285, I2S: 285
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 286, I2S: 286
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 287, I2S: 287
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 288, I2S: 288
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 289, I2S: 289
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 290, I2S: 290
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 291, I2S: 291
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 292, I2S: 292
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 293, I2S: 293
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 294, I2S: 294
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 295, I2S: 295
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 296, I2S: 296
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 297, I2S: 297
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 298, I2S: 298
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 299, I2S: 299
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 300, I2S: 300
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 301, I2S: 301
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 302, I2S: 302
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 303, I2S: 303
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 304, I2S: 304
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 305, I2S: 305
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 306, I2S: 306
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 307, I2S: 307
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 308, I2S: 308
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 309, I2S: 309
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 310, I2S: 310
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 311, I2S: 311
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 312, I2S: 312
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 313, I2S: 313
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 314, I2S: 314
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 315, I2S: 315
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 316, I2S: 316
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 317, I2S: 317
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 318, I2S: 318
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 319, I2S: 319
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 320, I2S: 320
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 321, I2S: 321
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 322, I2S: 322
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 323, I2S: 323
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 324, I2S: 324
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 325, I2S: 325
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 326, I2S: 326
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 327, I2S: 327
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 328, I2S: 328
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 329, I2S: 329
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 330, I2S: 330
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 331, I2S: 331
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 332, I2S: 332
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 333, I2S: 333
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 334, I2S: 334
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 335, I2S: 335
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 336, I2S: 336
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 337, I2S: 337
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 338, I2S: 338
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 339, I2S: 339
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 340, I2S: 340
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 341, I2S: 341
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 342, I2S: 342
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 343, I2S: 343
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 344, I2S: 344
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 345, I2S: 345
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 346, I2S: 346
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 347, I2S: 347
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 348, I2S: 348
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 349, I2S: 349
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 350, I2S: 350
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 351, I2S: 351
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 352, I2S: 352
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 353, I2S: 353
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 354, I2S: 354
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 355, I2S: 355
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 356, I2S: 356
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 357, I2S: 357
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 358, I2S: 358
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 359, I2S: 359
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 360, I2S: 360
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 361, I2S: 361
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 362, I2S: 362
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 363, I2S: 363
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 364, I2S: 364
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 365, I2S: 365
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 366, I2S: 366
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 367, I2S: 367
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 368, I2S: 368
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 369, I2S: 369
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 370, I2S: 370
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 371, I2S: 371
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 372, I2S: 372
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 373, I2S: 373
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 374, I2S: 374
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 375, I2S: 375
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 376, I2S: 376
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 377, I2S: 377
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 378, I2S: 378
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 379, I2S: 379
Imbalance: 0, SAI: 380, I2S: 380
Imbalance: 1, SAI: 382, I2S: 381
Imbalance: 1, SAI: 383, I2S: 382
...
```

Comment: Why do you say you are using the same clocks if the other uses PLL3P and other used PLL2P? What are the settings for PLLs, there's just 1... and 2... shown instead of actual values.

Comment: So I say same clock in terms of output frequency to the given peripheral. They are both 2.048 Mhz. The title has been edited. Thanks!

Comment: But they are different clocks. And their parameters are missing. What if there is an error and due to rounding both show 2.048 but you are seeing a rounded value? Nevertheless, what if you use PLL2P or PLL3P for both to guarantee that at least the master clock is synchronous? Also you I2S receiver is a clock slave, from where does it receive the clocks?

Comment: Good point... And I thought the same thing, the master I2S clock from the other device could be slightly off. However putting the peripheral in Master yielded the same result. 

This is my first STM32 project, so I'm unsure... I switched the SA1 to PLL2 so they can be fed by the same clock source. There was no change, still the same imbalance...

Comment: @Justme I tested again with the I2S Peripheral as master, both clock sources as PLL2. The imbalance is worse, in the opposite direction... Do you know if there is any other I2S settings to set, that may be skewing it by 1 bit or something else to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the external device resetting which caused it to drive the I2S BCLK on startup. Mystery solved.